# Web API response xml language

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am having this simple `POST` url to which my clients will send a `POST` request.

http://mydomain.com/requests/request

POST Data:

```
<Request>
<OrderId>1E008921</OrderId>
<OrderName>MC1</OrderName>
</Request>
```

to which I respond by sending back them a XML

```
<SRequest>
<RequestedBy>Client 1 </RequestedBy>
<RequestName>Test Name</RequestName>
<RequestStatus>Success</RequestStatus>
<SRequest>
```

Now client wants the above XML in a different language (say `French`)

How to handle this ? How to send the response language preference in Web API ? specially with the POST scenario like this ? (Append  a language string ? or what is the best practices ?)

Comment: Unsure if you've seen it, but there is a site from Microsoft on internalizaion: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/internationalization - it may be a big help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you either include it in URL: http://mydomain.com/fr/requests/request or use HTTP header like [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4). You could read more in the answer to: [Good way to changing language resources dynamically by request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078242/good-way-to-changing-language-resources-dynamically-by-request)