# Benefits from returning a "Task<int>" instead of an "int" in a WCF or WebAPI method (IIS)

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, task-parallel-library, task

Consider a time consuming **synchronous** method "Foo":

```
public int Foo(int id)
{
    // Do some expensive calculation
    return 42;
}
```

And a WCF Service hosted in IIS called "FooService" which calls "Foo":

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class FooService 
{
    public Task<int> GetFoo(int id)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => return Foo(id));
    }

    public int GetFoo2(int id)
    {
        return Foo(id);
    }
}
```

Do I get any benefits if I start and return a Task for Foo? Like - do I reduce load to the I/O Thread?

Comment: You should not be using `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` to wrap a synchronous, CPU-bound worker method in `ASP.NET`. All this does is just adding an overhead of a thread switch. An HTTP request calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` and returning it as a `Task` will take at least the same number of threads to complete, you will not improve scalability and only decrease the performance. OTOH, it does make sense for naturally IO-bound tasks, which don't use a thread while pending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tasks in WCF provide a more convenient API than that of the APM pattern (BeginXX/EndXX). Why should you use asynchronous calls in WCF? Because, when done correctly, it would lead to a much better thread utilization, which in turn, allows your application to be more scalable.

On the client side, having a task-based service contract, makes it easier to call a service without blocking a thread, waiting for the call to return. Even if the operation is a synchronous, CPU-bound operation on the server side, the client side would benefit from having a task. Also, with tasks, it's very simple to make the call synchronous again by calling `Task.Wait()` or `Task<T>.Result`.

On the service side, a task-based operation can be useful in several scenarios:

- You want to parallelize some CPU-bound actions
- You're doing IO (e.g. calling another service, reading a file, etc.)
- Any combination of the above

Every time a WCF operation is called, WCF grabs a thread from the thread-pool to handle the request. So there's no need to call `StartNew`, which queues an operation to the thread-pool (a completely redundant overhead):

```
public Task<int> GetFoo(int id)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => return Foo(id));
}
```

Instead, you can use `FromResult`, which creates a completed task object:

```
public Task<int> GetFoo(int id)
{
    return Task.FromResult(new Foo(id));
}
```

Lastly, if none of the above use cases are relevant, *and* your client API needs to be synchronous, there's no point in using tasks.

Comment: Thanks Eli. Most of the methods do some time consuming database queries so I think it is a good idea to return a Task. I thought using Task.Factory.StartNew will allow me to run more concurrents requests - while Task.FromResult won't?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, no, you won't get any benefit from spinning off a Task thread to do the work as described in your post. The reason is this: each WCF web service defined using WSHttpBinding or BasicHTTPBinding (can't speak to the others) will create its own independent thread for each incoming request, so I don't see the advantage. So if 10 requests coming at 12:00:01:00, each will get it's own thread from WCF automatically.

Now, if within each singular request you want threading to speed up some repetitive, time-consuming tasks, then you'd obviously benefit from setting up and managing threads through Task, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Please define *a time consuming synchronous method*

Overhead of asynchronous operations is not negligible. You should only use task if you are doing an **IO-bound** operation (calling another web service/API, reading a file, reading a lot of data from database or running a slow query).

Using async programming on server-side differs from client-side. We are not concerned by UI thread but by **scalability**. Using async programming on server-side will allow you to run thousands of concurrents requests.

This is very important since IIS 7, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910159/how-are-iis7-threads-assigned/4910207#4910207)

> ... in IIS 7.0 integrated mode, ASP.NET restricts the number of
>   concurrently executing requests. The difference only matters when the
>   requests are asynchronous (the request either has an asynchronous
>   handler or a module in the pipeline completes asynchronously).
>   Obviously if the reqeusts are synchronous, then the number of
>   concurrently executing requests is the same as the number of threads
>   concurrently executing requests, but if the requests are asynchronous
>   then these two numbers can be quite different as you could have far
>   more requests than threads.

Note : since .net 4.5, it's better to use Task.Run.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Most of the methods do some database queries which can take some time (1 - 5 seconds). So if I return a Task here, my Service can handle more concurrent requests? Please note the lack of the async keyword.

Comment: Thanks also for the Task.Run hint

Comment: @jisaak yes, and especially if you follow the asynchronous pattern all the way