# Does C# AsyncCallback creates a new thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, http, asynchronous

I have written an `HttpListener` which listens on one of the ports:

```
httpListener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), httpListener);
```

The `ListenerCallback` handles any request that is received on the listener uri. If exception occurs during handling request, it runs a diagnostics routine, which tries to hit listener uri just to check if the listener is in fact alive and listening on the uri and writes the log of response returned by the listener. Listener simply returns string `Listening...` to such dummy requests.

Now during testing, when exception occurred in other modules which resulted in the execution of the diagnostic modules, I can see the listener returned `Listening...` properly when I checked the logs.
However when exception occurred in the `ListenerCallback`, the attempt to hit the listener URI inside diagnostics threw following exception:

```
System.Net.WebException : The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at MyPackage.Diagnostics.hitListenerUrl(String url) in c:\SW\MyApp\MyProj\Diagnostics.cs:line 190
```

That line 190 in diagnostics module is as follows:

```
189     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
190     HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Now if `AsyncCallback` dispatches new thread and run `ListenerCallback` in that new thread, it must not result `Operation Timeout` when the dummy request is sent through the diagnostics. This is what I thought the desired behavior should be since it is `*Async*Callback`. In fact MSDN also [says the same](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Use an AsyncCallback delegate to process the results of an asynchronous operation in a separate thread.

But seems that is not the case. Am I missing something here?

Interpreting Visually:

[image]

Comment: "dummy request is sent through the diagnostics" isn't at all clear. It seems you're asking about your own theory, and that might very well be wrong.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have put that line 190 of diagnostics showing how I am sending request to the listener uri.

Comment: So a crashed Listener stops listening...

Comment: yess somewhat, does not stops listening exactly but is busy, since the diagnostics is running in listeners thread only and if `ListenerCallback` does not execute on the new thread then a request send to uri through `ListenerCallback`'s thread's diagnostics will never get any response. Added a diagram just check please. It logs `Operation Timeout` and comes out of diagnostics. But due to operation failures in `ListenerCallback`, another dependent thread (which has a loop) throws Exception and runs diagnostics in each loop. For those diagnostics `ListenerCallback` properly returns `Listening...`

Comment: ...The point is to tell that it is busy not stopped, when a dummy request is sent through diagnostics.

Comment: You keep mentioning some "diagnostic": what is that? Is it something you have in your program?

Comment: Its a class Diagnostics.cs, see in Stack Trace

Comment: I believe you misinterpret the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you linked. What they mean is the async callback will be called on a separate thread from the original thread, and that's where you should process the result of the operation. That's what `ProcessDnsInformation` in their sample code does.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is entirely an implementation detail of the class' BeginXxx() method.  There are two basic schemes:

- BeginXxx() starts a thread to get the job done, that thread makes the callback
- BeginXxx() asks the operating system to get job done, using an I/O completion port to ask to be notified when it is done.  The OS starts a thread to deliver the notification, that runs the callback.

The second approach is very desirable, it scales well with the program being able to have *many* pending operations.  And is the approach used by HttpListener, the TCP/IP driver stack on Windows supports completion ports.  Your program can support *thousands* of sockets easily, important in server scenarios.

The EndXxx() call in the callback reports any mishaps encountered while trying to complete the I/O request by throwing an exception.  In your case, the BeginGetContext() requires EndGetContext() in the callback.  If you don't catch the exception then your program will terminate.

Your code snippet does not actually demonstrate any asynchronous I/O.  You called GetResponse() instead of BeginGetResponse().  No callback is involved at all, it will thus be the GetResponse() method that fails and throws the exception.

Comment: ohkay now I think I understood it. But will appreciate some more information/links on how IO Completion ports are used to handle HttpListener callbacks. I think I need to read some bulk of stuff, may be some low level details of working of IO Completion ports and Windows Kernel Threads. But will still appreciate some related links if you have. (Linking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4841725/1317018) answer containing somewhat related material.)

Comment: They are a fairly advanced concept, truly understanding them requires basic knowledge of the way device drivers work.  Lots of books about it, Russinovich' Windows Internals is excellent.

Answer (score 7):

> **Does C# AsyncCallback creates a new thread?**

No, it does **not** itself, it is just a callback. However, the code which invokes the callback may be calling it on a thread **different** from the thread the original operation was started on (in your case, the operation is `httpListener.BeginGetContext`).

Usually (but not necessary), it is invoked on a random `ThreadPool` thread which happened to handle the completion of the underlying socket IO operation (for more details, here is a great read: [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)).

> Use an AsyncCallback delegate to process the results of an
>   asynchronous operation in a separate thread.

I believe that means you should process the results of an asynchronous operation **on the thread your callback is called on.** This thread is almost always separate from the thread which initiated the operation, as explained above. That's also what their [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) apparently does. Note they don't create any new threads inside `ProcessDnsInformation`.

Once you have received the callback, it is up to you then how to organize the threading model of your server application. The main concern is, it should remain being responsive and scalable. **Ideally, you should serve the incoming request on the same thread it arrives on, and release this thread as soon as you've done with any CPU-bound job required to process the request.** As a part of the processing logic, you may need to do other IO-bound tasks (access files, execute DB queries, call web services, etc). While doing that, you should be using asynchronous versions of the relevant APIs as mush as possible, to avoid blocking the request thread (again, refer to [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)).

IMO, with the [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pattern that you've chosen, implementing such logic might be quite a tedious task (especially, the error handling and recovery part of it).

However, using [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`async/await` pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx) and `Task`-based APIs like [`HttpListener.GetContextAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.getcontextasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it's a piece of cake. The best part: you don't have to worry about threading much any more.

To give you an idea of what I'm talking about, here is [an example of a low-level TCP server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018042/1768303). A very similar concept can be used while implementing an `HttpListener`-based HTTP server.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Hans' excellent answer,

Even when an asynchronous operation is performed, it is actually possible for it to complete synchronously -- even in scheme #2, it is incorrect to say callbacks will come back on another thread. Counting on that behavior might actually end up with you getting deadlocks or overflowing your stack.

You can check the `IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` property to determine this. When set to `true`, it is highly likely that the completion callback came in on the same thread that started the async operation: the callback will run during your `Begin*` call, and must complete before it can return.

Comment: A very good and important point. In which case, it actually might be a good idea to continue processing the result of operation on another thread (using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or `Task.Run`).

Comment: @Noseratio Yess something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9035023/1317018) right?

Comment: @Mahesha999, somethings like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9035023/1317018) does work, but it will blocks the thread from `ThreadPool` with the synchronous `GetContext` call. I'd go with `HttpListener.GetContextAsync`, which doesn't need a dedicated thread. You really don't need to master Kernel internals to take advantage of async APIs.